# Creating unique_ptr Via Functions

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

What's really going on here? I thought you weren't able/supposed to copy unique_ptr's however the following code compiles and runs properly:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> CreateObject()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>(new SomeObject);
}

//  Useage
auto MySomeObject = CreateObject();
```

Is the unique_ptr's move method being invoked? If so, is there a way to actually create the unique_ptr inside the function and return it without the object getting destroyed when the function scope exits?

I would rather not return the actual pointer then turn it into a unique_ptr as to force usage of unique_ptrs for objects returned by this function. Nor would I want to use shared_ptr's only to avoid the issue proposed in this question.

This is a very performance critical area of the application and I'm afraid extra overhead may be created here.

Comment: It's not copying the `unique_ptr`, it's **moving** it. The object is therefore **not** destroyed until `MySomeObject` is destroyed. Also, I'd be surprised if the above yields any overhead at all, since the RVO will very likely make sure that `MySomeObject` is initialized directly without calling any move-ctor.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely reassures me here. I wish you had posted as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: This was asked before but I'm having trouble finding the previous instance.

Comment: More importantly, I'd say the last paragraph is Wrong™. Copying a unique_ptr would be at most as slow as moving one. What you should be worried there is that copying a unique_ptr would lead to broken semantics, not slow code.

Comment: The concept behind `CreateObject` is part of C++14 and called [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought you weren't able/supposed to copy unique_ptr's

Indeed you can't. But you can move them, transferring ownership of the managed object from one smart pointer to another.

> Is the unique_ptr's move method being invoked?

Yes. A function's return value is moved if possible; and assignment from the temporary return value is also done by moving.

> is there a way to actually create the `unique_ptr` inside the function and return it without the object getting destroyed when the function scope exits?

Yes, that's exactly what's happening here. Moving a `unique_ptr` transfers ownership of the managed object; so here, ownership is moved from the temporary value of return expression, to the return value, to `MySomeObject`. (In practice, the first move will be elided; but the effect is the same).

> This is a very performance critical area of the application and I'm afraid extra overhead may be created here.

The extra overhead of moving a `unique_ptr` versus copying a raw pointer is:

- nulling the pointer when it's moved from;
- checking whether to delete an object when the pointer is destroyed.

It's unlikely that either of these will be significant, especially when compared with the cost of `new`.

Comment: On the performance points: probably a compiler can detect that the assignment has no effect and the check isn't needed. Profiling might give insights on performance aspects.